# wcf sending soap messages in JSON format

Tags: json, wcf, soap

I'm really new to .NET technologies.What i must implement is a wcf service which is soap-based but sends the messages in JSON format.I've been searching tutorials for days but still can get it to work.Can you point me to some helpful tutorial or tell what are the thin details that i should take care?Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use these links.. it will help you.

[wcf videos](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/79/posts/11541/wcf-free-training-videos.aspx)